# mutate and/or summarise a dynamic number of columns

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

In a previous question I wanted to carry out `case_when` with a dynamic number of cases. The solution was to use `parse_exprs` along with `!!!`. I am looking for a similar solution to mutate/summarise with a dynamic number of columns.

Consider the following dataset.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
data(mtcars)
mtcars = mtcars %>%
  mutate(g2 = ifelse(gear == 2, 1, 0),
         g3 = ifelse(gear == 3, 1, 0),
         g4 = ifelse(gear == 4, 1, 0))
```

Suppose I want to sum the columns `g2`, `g3`, `g4`. If I know these are the columns names then this is simple, standard dplyr:

```r
answer = mtcars %>%
  summarise(sum_g2 = sum(g2),
            sum_g3 = sum(g3),
            sum_g4 = sum(g4))
```

But suppose I do not know how many columns there are, or their exact names. Instead, I have a vector containing all the column names I care about. Following the logic in the accepted answer of my previous approach I would use:

```r
columns_to_sum = c("g2","g3","g4")

formulas = paste0("sum_",columns_to_sum," = sum(",columns_to_sum,")")

answer = mtcars %>%
  summarise(!!!parse_exprs(formulas))
```

If this did work, then regardless of the column names provided as input in `columns_to_sum`, I should receive the sum of the corresponding columns. However, this is not working. Instead of a column named `sum_g2` containing `sum(g2)` I get a column called `"sum_g2 = sum(g2)"` and every value in this column is a zero.

Given that I can pass formulas into `case_when` it seems like I should be able to pass formulas into `summarise` (and the same idea should also work for `mutate` because they all use the rlang package).

In the past there were string versions of `mutate` and `summarise` (`mutate_` and `summarise_`) that you could pass formulas to as strings. But these have been retired as the rlang approach is the intended approach now. The related questions I reviewed on Stackoverflow did not use the rlang quotation approach and hence are not sufficient for my purposes.

How do I summarise with a dynamic number of columns (using an rlang approach)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option since `dplyr 1.0.0` could be:

```
mtcars %>%
 summarise(across(all_of(columns_to_sum), sum, .names = "sum_{col}"))

  sum_g2 sum_g3 sum_g4
1      0     15     12
```

Comment: This also works with additional variables not in `columns_to_sum` eg: `summarise(num = n(), across(all_of(cols), sum, .names = "sum_{cols}")`.

Comment: But note `.names = cols` produces an error. Your output columns need different names from your input columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt gives the correct answer but do not give column names as expected.

Here's an approach using `map` to get the names correct :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(purrr)

map_dfc(columns_to_sum, ~mtcars %>% 
                         summarise(!!paste0('sum_', .x) := sum(!!sym(.x))))

#  sum_g2 sum_g3 sum_g4
#1      0     15     12
```

---

You can also use this simple base R approach without any NSE-stuff :

```
setNames(data.frame(t(colSums(mtcars[columns_to_sum]))), 
         paste0('sum_', columns_to_sum))
```

and same in `dplyr` way :

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(columns_to_sum), sum)) %>%
  set_names(paste0('sum_', columns_to_sum))
```